# why doesn't typescript accept if(Array.length) for differentiating between an object and array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I recently started using typescript and I've run into a confusing little part, where I don't quite get why typescript behaves like it does. (Involving typechecking a parameter that could either be an array or an object)

I first tried checking as the upper example shows, but it didn't work (Typescript didn't like me calling `.map`

Error Message: This expression is not callable.
Not all constituents of type 'string | ((callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' are callable.
Type 'string' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

I figured it had something to do with calling map on objects so I replaced the condition with Array.isArray() - and suddenly typescript was happy. - But why wasn't it before? - because in my mind objects wouldn't be able to pass regardless.

```
interface Object {
  [key: string]: string
}

function myFunction(a: string[] | Object) {
  if(a.length) {
    a.map(x => x)
  }
}
```

if I change the condition from `a.length` to `Array.isArray(a)` typescript realizes that objects won't pass this check - but why didn't it before? (since `a.length` will return undefined if called on an object - so the check would always fail if a was an object)

So I guess my question is: Why does typescript only accept `Array.isArray()` as a valid check in this case? - Or is there something else going on I am not aware of?

```
interface Object {
  [key: string]: string
}

function myFunction(a: string[] | Object) {
  if(Array.isArray(a)) {
    a.map(x => x)
  }
}
```

Comment: Erm, why would `a.length` mean it's an array? You've clearly defined `Object` can also have that property. Since it can have any and all properties. What is the logic TS needs to use to figure this out like you intended, rather than as you've told it? Also, an empty array will have a length of zero. So, it's not really differentiating between arrays and not arrays even then.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah there was a false assumption on my part (as the answers pointed out) - but that's kinda why I asked (since I also wanted to know if there were any false assumptions on my part) - and the length = 0 part would have been a intended side effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go for a canonical answer, the fact that `Object` can also have a `length` property is **not** the reason that disrimination fails here.

Consider the following scenario where only the array element in the union has a `length` property:

```
type T1 = string[] | {
    xyz: number
}

declare const a: T1

if (a.length) {}
//    ^^^^^^ Property 'length' does not exist on type '{ xyz: number; }'
```

TypeScript is not able to narrow down `a` even though the object does not have a `length` property. There  even is an error saying we can't access `length`. This is just not how narrowing is intended in TypeScript. The conditional as written above would only exclude `undefined` or `null` from `a.length`, but it would *not* discriminate between object unions.

The `in` operator however, *would* discriminate object unions.

```
if ("length" in a) {
    a
//  ^? const a: string[]
}
```

So technically, when using the `in` operator, you can discriminate between arrays and objects as long as the objects don't and can't have a `length` property. But since your object has an index signature, this would also not work for you. `Array.isArray()` is always the best option for this scenario.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAFQIxwLxwM5gE4EsB2A5gNoC6cAPnAN6hz1wAeEAXgFxz4CuAtgEYxsoAL6hQAExgBjADYBDbPCkB7fFjhyOyMSFwAzOAAo5AOhkwiYABYBKGqJCh9RgETnLVl3AIa7tEAwaoAD0wfQAegD8IkA)

---

> Why does `Array.isArray()` work?

The `Array.isArray()` method is defined with a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Comment: I've come to realize that narrowing is not as easy as I would like it to be. I guess I'll try to avoid using unions (where feasible). - Also: Until you mentioned "narrowing" in your answer I wasn't aware of how it was called (I knew what it was, but not how it is called - so looking for resources for that specific part was rather difficult)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```
interface Object {
  [key: string]: string
}

function myFunction(a: string[] | Object) {
  if(a.length) {
    console.log(`I think this is an array: ${a}; it's type is ${typeof a} and it ${Array.isArray(a) ? "is" : "isn't"} an array`);
  } else {
    console.log(`I think this is not an array: ${a}; it's type is ${typeof a} and it ${Array.isArray(a) ? "is" : "isn't"} an array`);
  }
}

myFunction(["a"]);
myFunction({ length: "hello" });
```

[link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFmQbwChlkBtAawgE8AuZAZzClAHMBdOx5kFwgX0KEYAVxC5gAexDIAtlQBio8VIAUcTk1ak2yAD5osOMAEoCxZMBhqAdABsIPMAAtTREiQRT6E+3YksVAAMASWRnUHIwp2B6C1i4aTgoKDhaZAASfDg+AG4LMAByWLAqAAcUGIz8EvKJGGRshpAAE3yqgEFk1OsYzpSqNVMAfmQAIhjR5Dpx+hACsFG+JoauqkDjHPMliFt6FDd3TxBvX1t-INDwkEjw2MqQCTwElf66TOy84ELisorYzJqEDqDSWCVaXw6qx69D6qUGyBGM0m0xicwWoMSq3WmxIAgEhDkijEYEkIBUpFGcFGbA2BIUShJqnwyHsjic0ycOzOkz4GyAA)

Any object can have the `length` property, not just arrays. If you want to go down the route of checking for a property, you could just check those you want to use:

```
interface Object {
  [key: string]: string
}

function myFunction(a: string[] | Object) {
  if(a.hasOwnProperty("map") && typeof a.map === "function") {
    const b = a.map(x => x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an incorrect assumption:

> since a.length will return undefined if called on an object - so the check would always fail if a was an object

Because you defined Object with `[key: string]: string`, it could very well have a `length` property, though it would be a string.

You can examine the following [proof in Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFmQbwChlkBtAawgE8AuZAZzClAHMBdOx5kFwgX0KCYAVxC5gAexDIWEMABkIPMAAsAFBLoZsuAJQFiJZFDnCo0iQDoANkpar+ghFMbIJWLVhx4AvAVvKKnQA5NZSLMEChM4grgAeyH6yCnaqGlj6yAD0WcgJwPRuMMhgVAAOKFysTi547pgAKgDummheuIkEUTHxAEydyYqB6ZiZOXnIBUUl5ZVM1UA):

```
interface Object {
  [key: string]: string
}


function getLength(o: Object) {
    return o.length
}

const obj: Object = {length: 'long'}

const x = getLength(obj)  // x is of type string

const objTwo: Object = {}

const x2 = getLength(obj)  // x2 is still of type string
```

The only failure I see in Typescript's type inference is that the return type of `getLength` should be `string | undefined`. I'm not sure why Typescript fails to figure this out.

Nonetheless, the fact that an Object instance *could* have a length property means your logic is incorrect.